# How to convert std::vector<uint8_t> to QByteArray?

Tags: c++, qt, vector, qbytearray

I am trying to create QByteArray from std::vector.. I tried;

```
std::vector<uint8_t> buf;
QByteArray img = new QByteArray(reinterpret_cast<const char>(buf), buf.size());
```

However it gives error;

```
error: invalid cast from type 'std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> >' to type 'const char'
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to cast `buf.data()` instead of `buf`:

```
QByteArray* img = new QByteArray(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(buf.data()), buf.size());
```

Comment: Note `.data()` is only available in C++11 and later. If your compiler doesn't support this, use `&buf[0]`.

Comment: when I use buf.data() it says `error: cast from 'unsigned char*' to 'const char' loses precision`

Comment: ohh.. my mistake, I didnt use char pointer.. thank you very much

Comment: I personally do avoid new and delete wherever I can. You can do on modern compilers like this: 
[auto img = QByteArray(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(buf.data()), buf.size());]